# On click of hardware button of mobile then it should exit from TIZEN application

Tags: javascript, tizen

I have developed tizen application and i want to use hardware button,once user click on hardware button it should exit from application.I am developing TIZEN
application.The hardware back button of my application is not working.

Answer (score 2):

There are two type of application is exist in TIZEN (2.3)

If you make web application,

```
document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
    if(e.keyName == "back") {
        try {
            tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("getCurrentApplication(): " + error.message);
        }
    }
});
```

but if you want native application, you can get back button event with [EFL Extension API](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__EFL__EXTENSION__EVENTS__GROUP.html)

```
#include <efl_extension.h>

static void
win_back_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
{
    appdata_s *ad = data;
    /* Let window go to hide state. */
    elm_win_lower(win);
}

eext_object_event_callback_add(ad->win, EEXT_CALLBACK_BACK, win_back_cb, ad);
```